# Bash Script Date: Day before 15th and last day of month but it has to be a week day

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting

I need to run a bash script every day using a cron job. For a sake of example let's say it will print Hello world but only on a certain condition. If it's the 14 of the month or the last day of the month. But if the 14th or the last day of the month falls on a Saturday or Sunday it should then instead print on the Friday before that Saturday or Sunday.

For example this month's (July 2016) last day of the month is the 31st (a Sunday), this script should print Hello world on July 29th since the last day of the month falls on a Sunday

Comment: Bash scripts can't time travel. If you need the script to run on Friday, you cannot wait until Sunday to initiate it. So your question makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: @rici Please, read the question carefully. OP says he needs to run the script _every day_ to check whether it's due for execution.

Comment: @uwe: yeah, that was my first thought. But how do you then explain "the script would have to back up two days?"

Comment: Perhaps you meant that the script should run if it is a weekday and the 14th or last day of the month, or if it is a Friday and the 12th, 13th, 2nd last or 3rd last day of the month?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @rici Yeah, that's what actualy sprung to my mind. The script runs on every weekday (via `cron`) and tests whether to continue execution or to abort. It continues if it is the 15th or the last day of the month or if it is a Friday and the 15th or the last day of the month falls on the next Saturday or Sunday which you already have translated in  the 12th, 13th, 2nd last or 3rd last day of the month. However, I admit that the wording of the question is not very clear. But the lack of clarity is perhaps the reason why the OP posted the Q.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question notifies you of the edit I have made, but I have re-worded the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a regular call in `cron` and what's beyond cron's possibilities in the script itself to exit if it shouldn't go or whatever. I don't know if that's a good practice, but it's a solution.

Comment: That would be also my recommendation. The script itself would need to determine if it's due for execution. This would require some arithmetic on dates and days of the week to be performed in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up a [[ cron job ]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) ?

```
# m  h  dom   mon dow   command
  *  16 1-15  *   1-5   /path/to/bakupscrtipt
```